# error: expected ';' before defining object of class

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class time
{
    private:
        int hour;
        int min;
        int sec;
    public:
        void get_time(int h,int m,int s)
        {
            hour = h;
            min = m;
            sec = s;
        }
        void show_time()
        {
            cout << "The time is: " << hour << "hours " << min << "minutes " << sec << "seconds";
        }
};

int main()
{
    time t1;
    t1.get_time(5, 4, 2);
    t1.show_time();
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
output:
    time.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
    time.cpp:25:7: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘t1’
      time t1;
           ^
    time.cpp:28:2: error: ‘t1’ was not declared in this scope
      t1.get_time(5, 4, 2);
      ^
```

Comment: unrelated to your question- if you have a `get_time` function it should conventionally return something. What you have should be `set_time`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My compiler gives some very useful diagnostics that explain exactly what's going on:

```
$ g++ test.cpp
test.cpp:25:6: error: must use 'class' tag to refer to type 'time' in this scope
            time t1;
            ^
            class 
/usr/include/time.h:118:8: note: class 'time' is hidden by a non-type
      declaration of 'time' here
time_t time(time_t *);
       ^
1 error generated.
```

I think the best strategy is to give your class a different name (perhaps `Time` with an uppercase `T`?)

Answer (score 3):

There is a global function called [`time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time), inherited from the C standard library. It hides your classes name, [basic.scope.declarative]/4:

> Given a set of declarations in a single declarative region, each of
>   which specifies the same unqualified name,
>
> - [..]
> - exactly one declaration shall declare a class name or enumeration name that is not a typedef name
>        and the other declarations shall [..] all refer to functions
>       and function templates; **in this case the class name or enumeration name is hidden (3.3.10).** [..]

The easiest solution is to give your class another name (e.g. `Time` - C and C++ standard libraries never use uppercase letters in identifiers).